# Changing the Origin of a Animation in Python and Pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, animation, pygame

I am currently working on a 2D platformer and the sprites that I have animate from the bottom left point of the animation and when I draw the animation using a x and y point it still animates from the bottom left, so when I draw the animation to the screen the sprite should get shorter but the sprites feet just lift up of the ground like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ofeggmlcp4f6qsk/Animation_probs_video.mp4
I know the video is not high quality but so what.
His head should go up and down not his feet. If you guy's can help me I would be most greatful. I could also use a program that fixes that I have a Linux computer with a windows xp virtual box and I am using python 2.7 and pygame.
Thanks.

Comment: Think about the geometry - the sprite is "scrunching" so the feet lift you need to adjust the y axis down to keep the feet on the ground (y gets larger)

Comment: I tried that and It was too complicated

Comment: The sprite is going to be moving all over the screen

Comment: If you could give me an example how to do that that would be great @gkusner

Comment: you are basically considering the entire sprite and moving its upper left corner but what you need to do is consider the actual visible part of the sprite and adjust the reference point based on where you want the feet to be - yes its complicated but to look right that is how you have to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are animating a series of rectangular sprites each being an instance of `pygame.Surface`, you will be adding the difference between the surface with the greatest height and the current sprite's surface to the y position every time you `blit`.

Find the height of the tallest sprite only once:

```
  max_height = tallest_sprite.get_height()
```

Now while you are cycling through your sprints each frame with current_sprite:

```
  screen.blit(current_sprite, (x, y+(max_height - current_sprite.get_height())
```

If framerate is an issue, you may want to calculate these differences beforehand and associate them with each sprite so you have one less `get_height()` call per frame.